# When to use 되다?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, verb, korean-to-english

I learned from a Talk to Me in Korean lesson that the verb 되다 means "to be done" or "to be possible," and is often used in the format (verb)+ 야 + 되다 to describe what one must or should do. However, I the dictionary definition on Naver is "to become." Then, in a drama I was watching, they said "됐어요" for "never mind" and "forget it." So now I'm extremely confused about the meaning and usage of this verb.

Answer (score 1):

되다 has over 20 kinds of different meanings. One of them is "do,be enough,to be all right or no problem." 국립국어원 says that this meaning is the closest one with "됐어요!", but it is more likely to be used as **an idiom** of which meaning is not listed in the dictionary.

Here is the original answer from 국립국어원:
"말씀하신 '됐어요'는 '되다'의 활용형이 맞습니다. 굳이 표준 국어 대사전의 내용을 고려한다면, 질문하신 의미의 '되다'는 '괜찮거나 바람직하다' 정도로 해석해 볼 수 있을 듯합니다. 다만 이와 같은 상황의 '되다'는 관용적인 표현으로 보이는데, 이러한 관용적인 표현에 대해서는 사전에서 풀이되지 않을 수도 있습니다. 이 점 감안해 주시기 바라며, 그렇다고 하더라도 이러한 관용적인 표현을 틀린 표현이라거나 표준어에서 벗어난 표현이라고 단정하기는 어렵겠습니다."